# Creating a file with python causes `FileNotFoundError`

Tags: python, file

I would like to create a new `.json` file in a different path than the python file is written in. My code is listed below and does not work.

```
import json

file_name = r'.\Data\Archive-' + str(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%a-%m/%d/%y-%I%p")) + '.json'

file = open(file_name, 'w')

file.dump({})
```

The error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is your error in this code ?

Comment: "does not work" is not a narrow, specific problem. There are things here that aren't good practice -- I would definitely suggest staying away from slashes in filenames, and to avoid shadowing built-in names like `file` -- but we can't say what is or isn't the problem you came here about unless you _tell us_ what problem you came here about.

Comment: if you want to save the data in json file in different folder: ```with open("different_folder_path.json", "w") as pf: json.dump(data, pf, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)```

Answer (score 3):

You most likely got (but you should really include that in your question):

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory <your path here>
```

Your construct the path as a string. Where I live that would currently become:

```
r'.\Data\Archive-Thu-09/22/22-07AM.json'
```

The forward and backward slashes are not an issue, Python deals with that nicely, but do you realise that the forward slashes are not allowed in file names, and will be interpreted as path separators?

So, it is trying to write `22-07AM.json` to the folder `r'.\Data\Archive-Thu-09\22\` - which is probably not what you want.

Try something like this:

```
import datetime as dt  # uncommon, most people use `from datetime import datetime`

file_name = r'.\Data\Archive-' + str(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%a-%m-%d-%y-%I%p")) + '.json'
```

If it *is* what you want, and Python should create those directories automatically, you can:

```
from pathlib import Path

Path(file_name).parent.mkdir(parents=True)
```

- `Path(file_name)` constructs a `Path` object from the string
- `.parent` takes the parent directory of the file represented by the `Path`
- `.mkdir()` creates that directory, and `parents=True` ensures needed parent directories are created as well.

Comment: So constructing my string like this: `file_name = r'.\Data\Archive-' + str(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%a-%m-%d-%y-%I:%m%p")) + '.json'` would work since I do not want to create more files and just want to create a file with this name.

Comment: Yes, or to be more precise, you don't want to create more *directories* and you cannot use a character like `/` (there's a bunch of characters you cannot use in file names, because they have other meaning in file systems)